# Using serial wacom Artpad II drawing tablet with unpatched Artful 17.10

Tags: wacom

Have you had any luck using a Wacom Artpad II serial tablet with an unpatched Ubuntu around 17.10?  All the google results seem to be about obsolete software, or for more modern (Intuos-era) tablets.

A trivial execution of  `inputattach -w8001 /dev/ttyS0` does not produce a new input device, and I'm not certain that this is the right protocol for this device... nor whether the wacom_serial4.ko kernel driver even supports it.

If you have had success, please share your xorg.conf.d and any kernel and userland configuration you had to do.

Answer (score 1):

Providing inputattach with the `-w8001` option tells it to try and set up the tablet for use with the kernel's "wacom_w8001" driver. This is likely the incorrect driver for your particular tablet since I believe it is only compatible with the serial digitizers/touchscreens found in tablet PCs. You likely need to pass the `-wacom_iv` option to inputattach instead. This will try to make use of the "wacom_serial4" kernel driver. I'm not sure if that driver supports the ArtPad II either, but it does have a suspicious-looking case to handle "MODEL_DIGITIZER_II" UD hardware...

You might contact the author (Julian Squires) of the wacom_serial4 driver for more information: you can find some contact info at the top of the driver source: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/tablet/wacom_serial4.c

Comment: Thanks, didn't have sufficient motivation for manual patching and integration.  Ended up finding a used Graphire, which worked out of the box.